# Generators Relations of the Weyl Group

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, quantum-groups

Suppose we have a [Root System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system) and call $s_{\alpha}$ the transformation $$s_{\alpha}\left(\beta\right)=\beta-\frac{2\left\langle \beta,\,\alpha\right\rangle }{\left\langle \alpha,\,\alpha\right\rangle }\alpha.$$
These transformations form a group called [Weyl Group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_group). What can I say about the presentation (i.e. generators and relations) of the Weyl Group associated to the root system of a Semi-simple Lie Algebra? Are the relations given in the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_group) the only relations or there are others?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: The relations given in the Wikipedia article give a presentation.

Comment: Ok so there are no other relations outside those given in the article?

Comment: That's ambiguous. Of course other relations hold; what it means for some generators and relations to give a presentation of the group is that every relation is deducible from the given relations.

Comment: No problem, Burde gave me the answer I was looking for. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there may be several presentations of a group - see K.Conrad's article on [Generating Sets](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/genset.pdf). A good example for this is the symmetric group. See the table after Example $1.8$ for the different possibilities. Actually, Weyl groups usually are given in the [*Coxeter presentation*](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0607562), but there are others.

Comment: Thank you, the second reference you gave is exactly what I needed.

Comment: You are welcome:)